# ScrollView disappears along with content when adding flex:1 to contentContainerStyle

Tags: react-native

When I add a fixed height style it works and the content is there but when I set it to flex:1 (the correct way) the scrollview disappears along with the content.

My code:

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
          <View style={{padding: 5}}>
            <Text>search</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{padding: 5}}>
            <Text>New Matches</Text>
            <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}} horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
              <View style={{padding: 10}}>
                <Thumbnail medium circle source={require('../assets/placeholders/profile1.jpg')}/>
                <Text>Christian</Text>
              </View>
              <Text>works</Text>
              <Text>works</Text>
              <Text>works</Text>
              <Text>works</Text>
              <Text>works</Text>
            </ScrollView>
```

Also, as you can see I have two scrollviews. I am referring to the outermost (the vertical scrollview).

Answer (score 7):

Wrap your outer ScrollView to a View component with `flex:1` style.

```
<View style={{flex: 1}>
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
...
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: The general idea is to give enough height for the container which contains the scroll view (I call it the `scroll-container`.)

(It also means giving enough height to the parent containers of the `scroll-container`). Because children are limited to the parent's height, so if you assign `flex:1` on the `scroll-container`, it will also disappear if the parent doesn't have enough space.

Comment: @AmirHossein Solved my problem. The outer `<View>` didn't have any style so no child would display because of that

Comment: @AmirHossein Your comment is a lifesaver, thank you!